# Nested TreeSet iterators - Java

Tags: java, nested, treeset

I'm trying to write a Java program that prints the Cartesian Product of two sets. I defined two TreeSets with iterators.

**The problem is** when I'm iterating around both sets (nested iterating) using *while* statement, only the the second *while* is completing all the elements. It seems that iterators are getting confused with each other.

```
while (iSet1.hasNext()) { // to iterate over the first set
        int i = iSet1.next();

        while (iSet2.hasNext()) { // to iterate over the second set
            int j = iSet2.next();               
            System.out.printf("(%d,%d)",i,j);
        } // end of inner while
    } // end of outer while
```

if set1 = {1,2} and set2 = {1,2} I'm getting this *output*:
(1,1)(1,2)
where the desired *output* is:
(1,1)(1,2)
(2,1)(2,2)

thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: Flup has it right; On a secondary note, you should really rename your iterators to something meaningful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to compute the cartesian product, you'll need to re-initialize the second iterator for each value of the first iterator.

```
while (iSet1.hasNext()) { // to iterate over the first set
    int i = iSet1.next();
    iSet2 = secondSet.iterator(); // <- re-initialize the iterator here
    while (iSet2.hasNext()) { // to iterate over the second set
        int j = iSet2.next();               
        System.out.printf("(%d,%d)",i,j);
    } // end of inner while
} // end of outer while
```